# Randomized Strings + Digits [4 formats]

Tags: python, string, random

```
for i in range(num):
    code = "".join(random.choices(
        string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits,
        k = 16
    ))

    file.write(f"{code}\n")
```

So this is a code I made which randomly generates 16 characters, I would like for the output to also be in different formats. These are all the formats:

```
XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX -- [18 chars] Letters + Numbers [All capital]
XXX XXX XXXX -- [10 chars] Only Numbers
XXXX XXXX XXXX -- [12 chars] Letters + Numbers [All Capital]
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX -- [16 chars] Letters + Numbers [All Capital]
```

I'd like it to do 1 of the 4 randomly [as well as the one I made] The problem I'm having is adding the "-"'s for the first one. It doesn't apply to the last two though, but for those ones there will be a space as indicated.

Comment: `"{}{}-{}{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}".format(*choices(ascii_uppercase + digits, k=16))` and so on

Comment: Slice syntax allows to select a part of a string. Those parts can be mounted together with characters like hyphens or spaces using e. g. an f-string or simple concatenation with plus operator.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```py
import random
from string import digits, ascii_uppercase

def get_random_template(filename: str, n: int) -> None:
    """Saves n randomly generated templates to filename."""
    t1 = "{}{}-{}{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}-{}{}{}{}".format(*random.choices(ascii_uppercase + digits, k=18))
    t2 = "{}{}{} {}{}{} {}{}{}{}".format(*random.choices(digits, k=10))
    t3 = "{}{}{}{} {}{}{}{} {}{}{}{}".format(*random.choices(ascii_uppercase + digits, k=12))
    t4 = "{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}".format(*random.choices(ascii_uppercase + digits, k=16))

    for i in range(n):
        random_template = random.choice([t1, t2, t3, t4])
        # Write template(s) file:
        with open(filename, 'a') as file_obj:
            file_obj.write(random_template + '\n')
    print(f'Successfully saved {n} file(s) to {filename}.')


if __name__ == '__main__': 
    get_random_template('myTemplatefile.txt', 10)
```

Comment: Sorry but I made a change to the original question so could you look at the first block of code and try to implement the last line of text ? Thank you

Comment: Let me know if this works for you. Please consider up voting if the code helps you out!

Comment: Okay thank you, which places do I change for the name of my file? Sorry I'm new at python

Comment: Where is says `myTemplatefile.txt`. This is your filename. Name it whatever you want.

Comment: Hmm, I am having an issue. It works great but I would like it so everytime it would be different. This is what the .txt shows.



FB-ZX98-FOMN-XJ3T
RAY5 CQWP H4MC
088 512 0341
088 512 0341
RAY5 CQWP H4MC
F7C1N5DBV879QCVU
FB-ZX98-FOMN-XJ3T
088 512 0341
088 512 0341
RAY5 CQWP H4MC

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to make a code block

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
import random
import string


def rand_int_char(num: int) -> str:
    return "".join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters.upper() + string.digits, k=num))


def rand_int(num: int) -> str:
    return "".join(random.choices(string.digits, k=num))


random_num = random.randint(1, 4)
if random_num == 1:
    # Case 1 : XX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX
    print(f"{rand_int_char(2)}-{rand_int_char(4)}-{rand_int_char(4)}-{rand_int_char(4)}-{rand_int_char(4)}")
elif random_num == 2:
    # Case 2 : XXX XXX XXX
    print(f"{rand_int(3)} {rand_int(3)} {rand_int(4)}")
elif random_num == 3:
    # Case 3 : XXXX XXXX XXXX
    print(f"{rand_int_char(4)} {rand_int_char(4)} {rand_int_char(4)}")
else:
    # Case 4 : XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    print(rand_int_char(16))
```